# Harmonic series sum approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

> Question: $ 1 + 1/2 + 1/3+\dots+ 1/n > 4.$
>   Find the range of smallest value of n.
>
> Answer: $n$ lies in $(20,60)$.
>
> Source: KVPY 2017.

To the best of my knowledge I find this series to be divergent and thus its sum can not be calculated. I couldn't think of a way to approximate value of $n$. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the sequence $H_n=1 + 1/2 + 1/3+\dots+ 1/n$ is strictly increasing and divergent. The question is asking for the minimal positive integer $n$ such that $H_n>4$.

Hint. Note that for any $n\geq 2$,
$$\ln(n)=\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{x}dx  <  H_n<  1+\int_{1}^n \frac{1}{x}dx=1+\ln(n).$$
See for example [Showing inequality for harmonic series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series)

Comment: How to find that integer then??

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I saw the answers on that thread but i don't get it. My knowledge is limited to highschool math and this is supposed to be a highschool problem. It would be great if you could explain at that level.

Comment: I gave you another reference. Is it better now?

Comment: Yup I got my answer. Thanks a lot 

Answer (score 6):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Making the problem more general, you want to find $n$ such that $H_n > p$ knowing that $n$ is large.

The series expansion of harmonic number being
$$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms, you then need to solve for $n$ the equation
$$\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}-p=0$$ the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$n=-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{e^{\gamma -p}}{2}\right)}$$ Since the argument is small, you can approximate, for small $t$
$$W(t)=t-t^2+\frac{3 t^3}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ Using $t=-\frac{e^{\gamma -p}}{2}$ this would give, in the real domain for $p=4$, $n\approx 30.1508$ while the "exact" solution would be $30.1533$.

If you want a simpler approximation, you could use the simplest Padé approximant
$$W(t)=\frac t {1+t}$$ which, for the general case, would give the simple
$$n\approx e^{p-\gamma }-\frac{1}{2}$$

**Edit**

The last expression seems to be a quite good approximation of the inverse of the harmonic number as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & e^{p-\gamma }-\frac{1}{2} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.02621 &  1.00000 \\
 2 & 3.64866 &  3.63868 \\
 3 & 10.7772 &  10.7735 \\
 4 & 30.1546 &  30.1533 \\
 5 & 82.8280 &  82.8275 \\
 6 & 226.009 &  226.009 \\
 7 & 615.215 &  615.215 \\
 8 & 1673.19 &  1673.19 \\
 9 & 4549.05 &  4549.05 \\
 10 & 12366.5 &  12366.5 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Later, searching the Internet, I found in $OEIS$ sequences $A118050$ and  $A118051$  where David W. Cantrell proposed by series reversion an extremely accurate solution
$$n=u-\frac 12  - \frac 1 {24\,u}+ \frac 3 {640\,u^3}- \frac {1525} {580608\,u^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{u^7}\right)\qquad \text{where}\qquad u= e^{p-\gamma }$$ which is, for sure, much more accurate for small values of $p$.

Using David W. Cantrell's expansion, we could make a good approximation of it using Padé approximant and get the shorter
$$n=u-\frac 12-\frac 1 u \frac{136080\, u^2+60941}{3265920\, u^2+1830000}$$

**Edit** *(four years later)*

Currently working around simple approximations of harmonic numbers and their inverse, I obtained
$$H_n \sim \frac{1}{2} \log
   \left(n^2+n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma-\frac{1}{12 \left(n^2+n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$  which has an asymptotic error of  $\frac{1}{80 n^4}$ and its inverse is
$$n\sim -\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{6 W(t)}-\frac{1}{4}}\quad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac{1}{2}e^{2(\gamma-H_n)}$$ Replacing $H_n$ by $p$ and repeating the same calculations as above, the new new estimates for the first values of $p$ are
$$\{0.996835,3.63850,10.7735,30.1533,82.8275\}$$ which is much better.

Answer (score 1):

To be more clear and simple:

Sum of harmonic serie:

$H(n) = \Sigma_{k=1,n}(1/n)   = 1 + 1/2 + .... 1 /n$

For approximation I use *Euler Mascheroni Constant*

it's  $\gamma \approx 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992$

A very nice and simple approximation is

$H(n) ~ \ln(n) + \gamma + 1/2n- 1/12n^2  $

So
$H(5) = 2.28333... \approx  2.28332$

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the harmonic series by using the fact that the nth partial sum of the harmonic series minus the natural logarithm of n approaches $\gamma$ as n approaches infinity